# $\binom{2p-1}{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{\! p^2}$ implies $\binom{ap}{bp}\equiv\binom{a}{b}\pmod{\! p^2}$; where $p>3$ is a prime?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, congruences

From $\binom{2p-1}{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{\! p^2}$ how does one get $\binom{ap}{bp}\equiv\binom{a}{b}\pmod{\! p^2},\,\forall a,b \in \mathbb N,\, a>b$; where $p>3$ is a prime ?

Comment: $\binom{ap}{bp}\equiv \binom{a}{b}\pmod{\! p^2}$ is true for all $p\ge 5$ with no other conditions needed. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330571/p-be-a-prime-number-then-is-it-true-that-p2-pa-choose-pb-a-choose-b?lq=1).

Comment: @user26486 : I know that , the point is I want to derive it from the first congruence , but am not able to get the manipulations ...

Comment: To me, the right hand statement seems to be stronger; it implies the left and a whole host of similar identities.

Comment: Both congruences actually hold modulo $p^3$. Did you mean to ask just about $p^2$?

Answer (score 2):

We can begin with Wilson's Theorem $(p-1)!=-1\mod p$. This allows $\dfrac{(kp-1)!}{(k-1)p!}=-1\mod p$, for example with $p=5$ and $k=2$, $9.8.7.6=3024\equiv-1\mod5$, because we are looking at $(kp-1)(kp-2)\dots ((k-1)p+1)$ in which the terms without a $p$ coefficient relate to Wilson's Theorem.

So we have $\binom{2p-1}{p-1}\equiv1\mod p^2$, using Wolstenholme's Theorem.

Similarly, $\binom{ap-1}{bp-1}\equiv 1\mod p^2$, and by dividing through by appropriate $p$'s we get to the result.

Comment: if we drop to mod p there is a simple proof of it (consider Pascal triangle mod p)

Comment: The right hand side of the congruence in the last line should be ${a-1\choose b-1}$. Also I don't see how the last line follows from what came before.

Answer (score 1):

We have two congruences
$$
(1)\hspace{1cm}{2p-1\choose p-1}\equiv 1\!\!\!\mod p^2,\hspace{10mm}\text{and}\hspace{10mm} {ap\choose bp}\equiv {a\choose b}\!\!\! \mod p^2,\,\, a,b,\in\mathbb{N}.\hspace{1.1cm}(2)
$$
We would like to obtain $(2)$ from $(1)$. Both congruences actually hold modulo $p^3$.

For $k$ an integer, define
$
c_k=(kp-1)(kp-2)\ldots(kp-p+1)
$.
We can write our binomial coefficients in terms of the $c_k$:
$$
{2p-1\choose p-1}=\frac{c_2}{c_1},\;\;\;\;\;{ap\choose bp}={a\choose b}\frac{c_a c_{a-1}\ldots c_{a-b+1}}{c_bc_{b-1}\ldots c_1}.
$$

Let $H_n:=1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}$ be the $n$-th harmonic number. We can compute
\begin{align*}
\frac{c_k}{c_1}&=\left(1-\frac{kp}{1}\right)\left(1-\frac{kp}{2}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{kp}{p-1}\right)\\
&\equiv 1-k\,p H_{p-1}\mod p^2,\tag{3}
\end{align*}
where for $r$, $s$ rational numbers we write $r\equiv s\!\!\mod p^n$ to mean $p^n$ divides the numerator of $r-s$. Thus $(1)$ is equivalent to the statement $H_{p-1}\equiv 0\mod p$. Now $(3)$ and $H_{p-1}\equiv 0\!\!\!\mod p$ imply $c_k/c_1\equiv 1\!\!\!\mod p^2$ for all $k$ (and so $c_i/c_j\equiv 1\!\!\!\mod p^2$ for all $i$, $j$), so we get $(2)$.

---

If instead we are interested in $(1)$ and $(2)$ mod $p^3$, we can strengthen $(3)$:
$$
\frac{c_k}{c_1}\equiv1-k\,pH_{p-1}+k^2\,p^2H_{p-1}(1,1)\mod p^3,
$$
where $H_{p-1}(1,1)$ is the value of the second elementary symmetric polynomial evaluated at $1,\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{p-1}$. The final term vanishes (it can be checked that $H_{p-1}(1,1)\equiv 0\!\!\mod p$), so the $p^3$ strengthening of $(1)$ is equivalent to $H_{p-1}\equiv 0\!\!\!\mod p^2$, which implies the strengthening of $(2)$.